# Can I install WIndows Management Framework 3 on WS 2008 r2 using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, windows-server-2008-r2

Can I use PowerShell to script an install of this? I already use module PSWindowsUpdate and would like to install KB2506143-x86 but it is not available as an update in get-WUInstall -KBArticleID. Need to run this on hundreds of machines and would like to avoid manually updating each from a browser.
Many thanks,

Answer (score 2):

I think this is not possible due to

> 1. Close all Windows PowerShell windows.

paragraph in [install instructions](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=34595).

Answer (score -1):

[Microsoft makes a supported product to correctly deal with your problem](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/windowsserver/bb332157.aspx), why are you trying to solve it with a homebrewed script?